# When Rotating a bitmap it cuts corners off

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing

I rotating some bitmap data in AS3.  When ever I start rotating the bitmap the corners get cut off.  I'm trying figure out what size the bitmap should be to fit the newly rotated bitmap.

The code Im currently using

```
var point:Point=new Point(BMPHolder.x+BMPHolder.width/2,BMPHolder.y+BMPHolder.height/2);
var RotateMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
var radains:Number = 45 * (Math.PI/180);

myMatrix.tx -= point.x;
myMatrix.ty -= point.y;
myMatrix.rotate(radains);
myMatrix.tx += point.x;
myMatrix.ty += point.y;

preApply = new BitmapData (BMPHolder.width,AdjustY, false);
preApply.draw(BMPHolder,myMatrix, null, null, null, false);
```

With the help of the answer i was able to get this working. This is the code I had to add.

```
       //Anchor point.
        xArray.push(0);
        yArray.push(0);

        xArray.push((BMPHolder.width * Math.cos(radains)) - (BMPHolder.height * Math.sin(radains)));
        yArray.push((BMPHolder.width * Math.sin(radains)) + (BMPHolder.height * Math.cos(radains)));

        xArray.push((BMPHolder.width * Math.cos(radains)) - (BMPHolder.y * Math.sin(radains)));
        yArray.push((BMPHolder.width * Math.sin(radains)) + (BMPHolder.y * Math.cos(radains)));

        xArray.push((BMPHolder.x * Math.cos(radains)) - (BMPHolder.height * Math.sin(radains)));
        yArray.push((BMPHolder.x * Math.sin(radains)) + (BMPHolder.height * Math.cos(radains)));


        var NewWidth:Number = MaxValue(xArray) - MinValue(xArray);
        var NewHeight:Number = MaxValue(yArray) - MinValue(yArray);

        myMatrix.tx -= point.x;
        myMatrix.ty -= point.y;
        myMatrix.rotate(radains);

        myMatrix.tx += Math.abs(NewWidth/2);
        myMatrix.ty += Math.abs(NewHeight/2);
```

I'm assuming that I could have used the matrix to find all the points but I just did it by hand to keep my sanity.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate your corner points, and then extract the maximum and minimum x and y values from the set of rotated points. You can then use those to compute the minimum size bitmap to hold the data. You'll want to something like the folioing pseudocode:

```
points = [[0,0], [0,height], [width,0], [width, height]]
points = xform(points, myMatrix)
minx = min(xcoords(points))
maxx = max(xcoords(points))
miny = min(ycoords(points))
maxy = max(ycoords(points))

newwidth = maxx - minx
newheight = maxy - miny
```

You will then need to translate your rotated bitmap by minx, miny to put it in the right spot.

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly is xform?

Comment: In this case xform stands in for applying the transformations in myMatrix to points.